# What's the best way to add a specific string to all column names in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, nlp, text-mining

I am trying to train a data that's converted from a document term matrix to a dataframe. There are separate fields for the positive and negative comments, so I wanted to add a string to the column names to serve as a "tag", to differentiate the same word coming from the different fields - for example, the word hello can appear both in the positive and negative comment fields (and thus, represented as a column in my dataframe), so in my model, I want to differentiate these by making the column names positive_hello and negative_hello.

I am looking for a way to rename columns in such a way that a specific string will be appended to all columns in the dataframe. Say, for `mtcars`, I want to rename all of the columns to have "_sample" at the end, so that the column names would become `mpg_sample`, `cyl_sample`, `disp_sample` and so on, which were originally `mpg`, `cyl`, and `disp`.

I'm considering using `sapply`or `lapply`, but I haven't had any progress on it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should look into `sprintf` and `paste`. Can you provide a small reproducible example?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll edit the question to illustrate an example of what I want to try to achieve. I'll also look into those.

Answer (score 5):

Use colnames and paste0 functions:

```
df = data.frame(x = 1:2, y = 2:1)
colnames(df)
```

[1] "x" "y"

```
colnames(df) <- paste0('tag_', colnames(df))
colnames(df)
```

[1] "tag_x" "tag_y"

Answer (score 3):

If you want to prefix each item in a column with a string, you can use `paste()`:

```
# Generate sample data
df <- data.frame(good=letters, bad=LETTERS)

# Use the paste() function to append the same word to each item in a column
df$good2 <- paste('positive', df$good, sep='_')
df$bad2  <- paste('negative', df$bad,  sep='_')

# Look at the results
head(df)
  good bad      good2       bad2
1    a   A positive_a negative_A
2    b   B positive_b negative_B
3    c   C positive_c negative_C
4    d   D positive_d negative_D
5    e   E positive_e negative_E
6    f   F positive_f negative_F
```

**Edit:**
Looks like I misunderstood the question. But you can rename columns in a similar way:

```
colnames(df) <- paste(colnames(df), 'sample', sep='_')
colnames(df)
[1] "good_sample"  "bad_sample"   "good2_sample" "bad2_sample"
```

Or to rename one specific column (column one, in this case):

```
colnames(df)[1] <- paste('prefix', colnames(df)[1], sep='_')
colnames(df)
[1] "prefix_good_sample" "bad_sample"         "good2_sample"       "bad2_sample"
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @smacdonald. I wanted to rename the columns instead of the values. Do you think using `paste` with indices would be an effective way?

Answer (score 3):

You can use setnames from the data.table package, it doesn't create any copy of your data.

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2),b=c(3,4))
#   a b
# 1 1 3
# 2 2 4
setnames(df,paste0(names(df),"_tag"))
print(df)
#   a_tag b_tag
# 1     1     3
# 2     2     4
```